# Comparing 2 FileAttributes must always return true in C#

Tags: c#, file

I recently got some great help here on stackoverflow. One of the answers puzzled me somewhat and I didn't feel it was appropriate to get an explanation due to the limitations of the comments box.

Please review the code below.

```
if ((File.GetAttributes(fileName) & FileAttributes.Archive) == FileAttributes.Archive)
{
    // Archive file.
}
```

My question is why would you include the logic after the & (see bold)
    (File.GetAttributes(fileName) **& FileAttributes.Archive**) == etc

Surely FileAttributes.Archive == FileAttributes.Archive will always match?

Does any one have an explanation to this (IMO it's probably a typo/mistake but I've assumed too many things before to only be corrected later on!)

The second question is what does the tilde `~` do in this code:

```
File.SetAttributes(fileName, File.GetAttributes(fileName) & ~FileAttributes.Archive);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some Enums are flags. That is, it can have any combination of the members of the enum and still be valid.

In the case of the `FileAttributes` enum, a file can be `ReadOnly` and `Hidden` at the same time. Likewise a file could be `Hidden`, `ReadOnly` and `System`. Writing an enum member for each combination would give 16 different members! Very inefficient.

When using flag-type enums, the way to check whether a value contains a specified enum member is to compare it with itself in a bitwise (binary) fashion.

Given the following simplified definition of the `FileAttributes` enum:

```
[Serializable, Flags]
public enum FileAttributes
{
    Archive = 32,
    Hidden = 2,
    Normal = 128,
    ReadOnly = 1,
    System = 4,
    Temporary = 256
}
```

A `System` file which is also marked `ReadOnly` will have the value `5` (`4 + 1`).
Trying to determine if the file is `ReadOnly` by using the code

```
File.GetAttributes(fileName) == FileAttributes.System
```

will evaluate as such:

```
5 == 4
```

and the result will be **`False`**.

The best way to determine whether the file has got the `System` attribute set is to do binary AND operation on the file's attribute and the attribute whose presence you want to determine. In code, you would write this:

```
(File.GetAttributes(fileName) & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System
```

This strips off all other attributes other than the `System` attribute before doing the comparison. Mathematically it would evaluate as such:

```
    0101  (System + Hidden)
AND 0100  (System)
--------  -----------------
    0100  (System)
```

Then the result (`0100`) would be compared to the System attribute (`0100`) and the result would then be **`True`**.

On one line, the code would be `(0x0101 & 0x0100) == 0x0100` which evaluates to **`True`**.

Starting from .NET 4.0, Microsoft has included the [`Enum.HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method to determine the presence or absence of flags in an enum value. You therefore do not have to type all that code yourself. When dealing with an Enum type that has the `Flags` attribute, you can simply use the `HasFlag` method to check if a particular flag is present. Your line would therefore be written as

```
File.GetAttributes(fileName).HasFlag(FileAttributes.System)
```

---

The tilde (`~`) mark, when used on a numeric value (or any type which can be 'degenerated' into `int`, `uint`, `long` or `ulong`), has the effect of flipping the bits on the number, producing the number's complement (all other values except the one specified).

For example, given the 16-bit number 4 (`0x0100`), it's complement (`~4`) would be 11 (`0x1011`)

```
0100 -> 1011
```

The tilde mark has the same effect as doing an `XOR` on the highest value of the type being compared. For a 16-bit number, the highest value would be 15 (`1111`) so your tilde will evaluate as:

```
    0100
XOR 1111
--------
    1011
```

The effect in your code `File.SetAttributes(fileName, File.GetAttributes(fileName) & ~FileAttributes.Archive)` will therefore get the file's attributes, ***remove*** the `Archive` attribute and then set it back to the file.

Assuming the file's attributes are Archive + Hidden, it will have a value of 34 (`0x00100010`) and `~Archive` will have a value of `0x11011111`.
Evaluating will be as such

```
    (Archive + Hidden)     0x00100010
AND         (~Archive)     0x11011111
----------------------     ----------
                Hidden     0x00000010
```

The file's attributes will subsequently be changed to Hidden only (the Archive attribute will be removed).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) has the [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) attribute. Means all the values can be combined (e.g. Archive AND Hidden).

To find out if really a specific value is set you have to mask out all the other values. For this purpose also the [`HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method within the [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zt1ybx4.aspx) class exists which could be used as follows in your example:

```
if(File.GetAttributes(fileName).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Archive))
{
    // Archive file.
}
```

The second example does removing an exact value out of the bitmask. So it removes the archive attribute without touching all the other bits within the mask (e.g. readonly or hidden). For this task no method exists within the enum class.

Answer (score 2):

The File.GetAttributes method returns an enumeration which has a Flags attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values. In other words, all the bit values of ALL of the relevant attributes are combined together in a single integer object. The '&' or bitwise and operator allows you to pull out the relevant bits of the object. The comparison with the original attribute is for clarity, it would be equally logically correct to simply look for a non-zero value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is a so named masked comparison.

```
(File.GetAttributes(fileName) & FileAttributes.Archive)
    return FileAttributes.Archive
```

if there is a FileAttributes.Archive in attributes and return false in any other case.

#### Example:

if file attributes has value:

```
hidden  archive readonly 
   1       1       0
```

bitwise and `(File.GetAttributes(fileName) & FileAttributes.Archive)`

returns

```
hidden  archive readonly 
   0       1       0
```

and it is equal `FileAttributes.Archive`.

if file attributes has value:

```
hidden  archive readonly 
   1       0       1
```

bitwise and `(File.GetAttributes(fileName) & FileAttributes.Archive)`

returns

```
hidden  archive readonly 
   0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

The '~' operator is a bitwise NOT (complement). See [Bitwise Complement Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-complement-operator)

Comment: I could spend the rest of my life reading that and it will never make sense!  :) Straight from MS site: The ~ operator performs a bitwise complement operation on its operand   ... I guess this is written for those who already understand it :)

Comment: Admittedly the msdn article is less than helpful given the code example. The wikipedia article probably provides better context (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT). I think in terms of you question, the code will essentially switch 'on' or 'off' the FileAttributes.Archive attribute.